# How can i get all subnode values separately from XML Response using LINQ to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

My XML Response:

```
<Items>
<Item>
<ASIN>1212121</ASin>
 <ItemAttributes>
  <Title>aaaa</Title>
  </ItemAttributes>
  <Variations>
   <Item>
    <ItemAttributes>
     <color>Red</color>
     </ItemAttributes>
     </Item>
     Item>
    <ItemAttributes>
     <color>yellow</color>
     </ItemAttributes>
     </Item>
       Item>
    <ItemAttributes>
     <color>pink</color>
     </ItemAttributes>
     </Item>
      </Variations>
    </Item>
  <Item>
   ASIN>1211111</ASin>
 <ItemAttributes>
  <Title>bbb</Title>
  </ItemAttributes>
  <Variations>
   <Item>
    <ItemAttributes>
     <color>Green</color>
     </ItemAttributes>
     </Item>
      </Variations>
  </Item>
  </Items>
```

Here, I received ten Item Per Page. All i need now, to Get the color of each Item.
   I used the following code.

```
   var Color = xd.Descendants(ns + "Items").Elements(ns+"Item").Elements(ns + "Variations").Elements(ns + "Item").Elements(ns + "ItemAttributes").Elements(ns + "Color").Select(cl => new
        {
            clr = cl.Value
        }).ToList();
```

This Xml Return the color of all Item. In first  it is red.
 In second  it is green. It goes upto item ten.
Now my above LINQ code return color for all Item., It return as Red,yellow.pink,green..
But I have to show the color of first item (Red)  separately.

Finally, 
  i have to show items->Item->Variations->Item->ItemAttributes->color
   Output: For First Item.,  Red,Yellow,Pink
     For second item , Green,..

Comment: *Which* item? You haven't given us enough information about what you're trying to do.

Comment: That one was amazon response., It is for apparel.,

Comment: No, I think you've missed my point. You've written: "How can i get associate color for  Single  item" - without knowing *what you've got* to represent that item, we can't possibly answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with,

```
   var Color = xd.Descendants(ns + "Items").Elements(ns + "Item").Select(o => string.Join(",", o.Elements(ns + "Variations")
            .Elements(ns + "Item")
            .Elements(ns + "ItemAttributes")
            .Elements(ns + "Color")
            .Select(x => x.Value).ToArray())).ToList<string>();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's still not 100% clear what you need, but I suspect it's something like this:

```
foreach (var item in xd.Descendants(ns + "Items").Elements(ns + "Item"))
{
    // Do anything you need on a per-item basis here
    Console.WriteLine("Got item: {0}", item.Element("ASIN").Value);
    var colors = item.Elements(ns + "Variations")
                     .Elements(ns + "Item")
                     .Elements(ns + "ItemAttributes")
                     .Elements(ns + "Color")
                     .Select(x => x.Value);
    foreach (var color in colors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  Color: {0}", color);
    }
}
```